# Git carries old commit messages from PRs that have been merged

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, pull-request

I have a branch, I used it for `PR1`, which was merged, and then I did `git pull origin master`, and merged with master. I am now using the same branch to submit another PR - `PR2`, but realize it carries the commit messages from `PR1`. How should I get rid of those messages?

Comment: What PR tool are you using? When you say messages do you mean commits?

Comment: Using github. Yes I meant the commits. git commit -m "****", I meants that message in the quotes.

Comment: You can’t get rid of them as they exist as part of the branch.

Comment: so I would have to use a different branch each time I submit changes?

Comment: It is quite a usual practice to use a different branch for each change or feature or bug fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, do not reuse branches once they've been merged. Use one branch per feature: [feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). Once a branch has been merged, delete the branch, and make a new one for the next PR.

You don't want to have to redo your new commits on the old branch. We can sort this out with `git rebase master`. Here's how it works.

You have a branch with some commits.

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E [feature]
```

It was merged.

```
A - B - C ------ F [master]
         \     /
          D - E [feature]
```

Now you've added more commits onto the same branch.

```
A - B - C ------ F [master]
         \     /
          D - E - G - H [feature]
```

We want a branch with just the new commits G and H. There's various ways to accomplish this. Simplest is to `git rebase master`. This will replay your branch's commits on top of the current `master`.

```
A - B - C ------ F [master]
         \     /  \
          D - E    G1 - H1 [feature]
```

`git rebase` will recognize that `master` already contains the content of D and E, so they're skipped. G and H will be replayed on top of `master` and given new commit IDs, here represented by G1 and H1.

Now you can push `feature` as a new PR and only G1 and H1 will show up. Once it's merged be sure to delete that branch and use a fresh one for a new PR.